# How are OPC UA namespace used?

Tags: opc-ua

I'm very new to the OPC UA and would appreciate your help with stuff that seems to be basic but I can't grasp it in full.

I'm exploring a publicly available OPC UA server at [opc.tcp://opcuaserver.com:48010](http://opcuaserver.com/).

Here's the tree of nodes it exposes:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out what's the logic behind assigning namespaces here.

| Path | Node Id | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Objects | `i=85` | (I understand ns=0 is the default one and is omitted) |
| Objects/Demo | `ns=2;s=Demo` |  |
| Objects/BuildingAutomation | `ns=3;s=BuildingAutomation` | Why is it in a different namespace while it's under same parent? |
| Objects/BuildingAutomation/ControllerConfigurations | `ns=3;s=ControllerConfigurations` | `BuildingAutomation` is not part of the prefix? |
| Objects/BuildingAutomation/AirConditioner_1 | `ns=3;s=AirConditioner_1` | Why doesn't it have `BuildingAutomation` in the prefix? |
| Objects/BuildingAutomation/AirConditioner_1/Temperature | `ns=3;s=AirConditioner_1.Temperature` | Why does it have `AirConditioner_1` in the prefix? |

Is it that we see multiple trees (each having its own namespace) merged here? Where do these trees come from? How namespace is assigned?

What's the logic behind node IDs without prefixes (ex. `ControllerConfigurations` ) vs with prefixes (ex. `AirConditioner_1.Temperature`) (as both seem to be attributes?)

Answer (score 3):

[Here is a great explanation](https://documentation.unified-automation.com/uasdknet/3.0.10/html/L2UaAdrSpaceConceptNamespaces.html).

Each namespace is a different model (tree of data):

**Namespace 0** is defined by the OPC Foundation and contains OPC Core nodes that you cannot modify.

**Namespace 1** is specific to your server can contains server info like certificates and open connections.

**Namespace 2 ... n** is where your business objects are.